# The whole res folder won't be pushed to github from Android Studio Project

Tags: android, git, android-studio

For the past few months, I can't push the whole res folder to my github and gitlab repos. I uninstalled my Android studio and tried using Sourcetree as well. None of these worked. I tried from a different computer and was able to push my code but not sure why I can't do it on my own computer. 
[The content of my res folder in my repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4yCo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Project view` on Project. then right click on `res` folder and use `git -> add` menu. now after your changes, res folder can be commit and push to remote branch. also check the current branch name in right|bottom of android studio.

[here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-git-in-android-studio--cms-30514) is tutorial for Git in android studio.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your comment but it did not work!

Comment: are you sure that you are add all of `res` directory to local branch? are sure that local branch and remote branch is same?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer to my question. .gitignore_global was excluding the xml files from pushing to my git repository. I modified it and that fixed the problem.